# C# exporting/merging DataGridView rows to Word Template

Tags: c#, ms-word, export

Apologies. I am new to StackOverflow and didn't how to respond with code examples. The code below is for exporting all rows from a datagridview table into a word document with merge fields. At the moment, the code below only repeats the first row in the document and does not show the rest of the rows. Someone mentioned this may not be possible the way I have written this. I know to know how if that's the case.

private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"C:\Users\euan\documents\agreementtemplate.docx");
        application.Visible = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < gvCurrentAgreements.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var griddescripton = gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            var gridprice = gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            var gridquantity = Convert.ToString(gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in document.Fields)
                if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Description"))
                {

                    field.Select();
                    application.Selection.TypeText(griddescripton);
                }
                else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Price"))
                {

                    field.Select();
                    application.Selection.TypeText(gridprice);
                }
                else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Quanitity"))
                {

                    field.Select();
                    application.Selection.TypeText(gridquantity.ToString());
                } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what, exactly, is your question? Please use the [edit] link below your question to add that AND to fix the code formatting so that it's readable as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple but sometimes we need to step back and take a break before we can see what is happening. You are assigning your variables outside of the loop and never again. You must do this inside the loop and grab row `i`, not Current Row.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gvCurrentAgreements.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    griddescripton = gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    gridprice = gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    gridquantity = Convert.ToString(gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    //...etc.
```

But if  you are data binding the grid I would prefer using the data source over manipulating the grid directly.

Comment: Tried both suggestions and still doing the same. The first row is repeated on the document. From the stepping through debugging, it just keeps cycling through the foreach loop then finishes. It will only increment the for loop once the there are no more fields left in the template?

Comment: Unless all rows in your grid have the same data, that is impossible. More likely you did not quite implement the code as shown. Could you add an update to your question with exactly what your code looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the values in each row:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < gvCurrentAgreements.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var griddescripton = gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    var gridprice = gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    var gridquantity = Convert.ToString(gvCurrentAgreements.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in document.Fields)
    if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Description"))
    // etc
```